# How to assign a value to the original datarow after I am iterating over a temporary datatable

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, ado.net

I am trying to explain what I need to do.

As you can see in the second foreach, I am iterating over the temporary data table, but I need to set a value for the same row in the original data tablerow.
For example:
   _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface[0]["property"] = x;

What I dont know how to implement is how to find that row and set the property, I saw the LoadRow method but I never used it before.

```
            DataTable tempTable = _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Clone();

            DataRow[] datarows = _uc090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterface.Select("REFMDossierID = " + refmDossierId);

            if (datarows.Length > 0)
            {
                foreach (DataRow dr in datarows)
                {
                    tempTable.ImportRow(dr);
                }
            }


           //2.     foreach master row
            foreach (UC090_WingsIntegrationDataSet.WingsBookingInterfaceRow row in tempTable.Rows)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the row using `Rows.Find()`, but it requires that a PrimaryKey be set on at least one column in your DataTable.

As far as loading new data, you can use `LoadDataRow()` which will update existing rows (if a primary key is supplied) or insert new data if any matching datatypes are found.

Please take a look at the following example using untyped datasets:

```
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet("MyDataSet");
DataTable dataTable = dataSet.Tables.Add("JavaScriptLibraries");

DataColumn[] dataColumns =
    new[] {
        new DataColumn("Id", typeof(Int32))
            {
                AutoIncrement = true, 
                AllowDBNull = false, 
                AutoIncrementSeed = 1
            }, 
        new DataColumn("Name", typeof(String))
    };
dataTable.Columns.AddRange(dataColumns);
dataTable.PrimaryKey = new[] { dataTable.Columns["Id"] };

DataRow dataRow1 = dataTable.NewRow();
dataRow1["Name"] = "jQuery";
dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow1);

DataRow dataRow2 = dataTable.NewRow();
dataRow2["Name"] = "MooTools";
dataTable.Rows.Add(dataRow2);

// Copy the dataset
DataSet tempDataSet = dataSet.Clone();
DataTable tempDataTable = tempDataSet.Tables["JavaScriptLibraries"];
DataRow[] tempRows = dataSet.Tables["JavaScriptLibraries"].Select("Name = 'jQuery'");

// Import rows to copy of table
foreach (var tempRow in tempRows)
{
    tempDataTable.ImportRow(tempRow);
}

foreach (DataRow tempRow in tempDataTable.Rows)
{
    // Find existing row by PK, then update it
    DataRow originalRow = dataTable.Rows.Find(tempRow["Id"]);
    originalRow["Name"] = "Updated Name";
}

// Load new data using LoadDataRow()
object[] newRow = new[] { null, "New Row" };
dataTable.BeginLoadData();
dataTable.LoadDataRow(newRow, true);
dataTable.EndLoadData();
```